# Laravel 5 migrating on existing DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an existing DB which was made with a different framework, and now I am extending the functionality to make Laravel API to work with that DB. I have successfully connected to the DB, and API responses are correct (which means `.env` values are set right), however I get an error when trying to do the new migration.

This is the error I am getting:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   Operation timed out (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
>   where table_schema = xxx and table_name = l_migrations)
>
> at
>   /Users/xxx/Projects/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
>       660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>       661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>       662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>       663|         catch (Exception $e) {
>
> > 664|             throw new QueryException(
> >         665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> >         666|             );
> >         667|         }
> >         668|
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out")
>         /Users/xxx/Projects/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
> 2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=192.168.0.1;port=3306;dbname=xxx",
>   "xxx", "xxx", [])
>         /Users/xxx/Projects/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

I have also tried doing the `php artisan migrate:install` but the `migrations` table won't get created and I suppose that is the issue.

On the side note, I am using `DB_PREFIX` in `.env` and have set it in `database.php` like this:

```
'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', '')
```

On the other side note, DB is on a separate Docker container.

Comment: My guess would be that your laravel environment cannot find / connect to the database. Check your DB host, port and whether you can access it from the other docker instance (ping it in a script or something). Also, make sure your Mysql DB allows connections for the specified user from outside of localhost https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/3240068. Unfortunately I cannot give you docker specific answers, but you could at least debug and see if having DB on a separate docker container is indeed the problem, and if so, seek help specifically for this docker situation.

Comment: Yeah, but what is strange is that I can fetch data from the DB. So connectivity and credentials shouldn't be a problem. `Model::all()` actually gets all models from the same DB.

Comment: Have you checked permissions for the user? Perhaps the user does not have create priviliges? Outside of that, I have nothing more to suggest.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on apache increase time out to 600 or 1000 in apache config file.